# How to include header files with E-ACSL wrapper script?

Tags: c, frama-c, acsl

I am new to Frama-C and wanted to ask how I could add header files when using the E-ACSL wrapper script. Normally, I've been adding header files the following way with WP and RTE:

```c
frama-c -rte main.c -cpp-extra-args="-I src/include -I ..."
```

However, I am unsure of how I can include these files when using the wrapper script.

```c
e-acsl-gcc.sh --rte=all -c main.c
```

Without the header files I run into the following error:

```
[kernel] Parsing main.c (with preprocessing)/main.c:10:10: fatal error: header.h: No such file or directory #include "header.h"
```

I am using Frama-C 24.0 (Chromium). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `e-acsl-gcc.sh -h`, you'll get a help message with the script's options:

```
Options:
  -h         show this help page
  -c         compile instrumented code
  (...)
  -E         pass additional arguments to the Frama-C preprocessor
  -F         pass additional options to the Frama-C command line
  (...)
```

The two above are relevant for you: `-E` adds arguments to an implicit `-cpp-extra-args` used by the script, while `-F` allows you to add the option itself.

So, you can either run:

```
e-acsl-gcc.sh -E "-Isrc/include -I..." <other options and source files>
```

Or:

```
e-acsl-gcc.sh -F -cpp-extra-args="-Isrc/include,-I..." <other options and source files>
```

Note that with `-F`, due to quoting issues (between e-acsl-gcc.sh, Frama-C's command-line, C preprocessor, etc), you may need to replace spaces with commas, as in `"-Isrc/include,-I..."`.

**Important**: do **not** add spaces between `-I` and the directory name. Due to parsing issues, `e-acsl-gcc.sh` will not parse it correctly if you do. GCC accepts both syntaxes anyway, so I'd recommend getting used to not adding spaces after `-I` (and `-D` as well) in general.

Overall, using `-E` is better here, but `-F` can be used to pass other options besides `-cpp-extra-args`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried this, which got rid of the error. However, now when I run the wrapper script, nothing is printed or returned (no files are generated). I noticed that this is happening when I add a `-I` to the `-E` option. I'm thinking this might be an issue with how the code is annotated or the installation, but I'm not sure what could cause such an issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it; with my very simple test file including headers in subdirectories, adding `-E` has no impact on the code generation, I still get messages such as `[kernel] Parsing file.c`, `[e-acsl] beginning translation.`, and `[e-acsl] translation done in project "e-acsl"`. I'm afraid that more details or an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might be necessary to better understand it. Maybe this could be done in a separate question, since I think the current question/answer is self-suffficient and possibly useful for others.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have at least one `[e-acsl]` message emitted when you run it? Otherwise, could you please show the entire `-E` argument you are using? If there are parsing/quoting issues, it's easier to understand with a concrete example.

Comment: I am not getting any messages when I run the script using the `-I` flag. It's as if I am entering nothing to the console. Here is a simplified version of the argument I am using, which has the same issue: ``e-acsl-gcc.sh -c main.c -E "-I src/include"`` . I can create another question if more information is needed.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add an important detail: do **not** put spaces between `-I` and the directory name. I had them changed in my own test case and incorrectly assumed your version might work. I'll update the answer to include this.