# E-ACSL wrapper script not creating files

Tags: c, frama-c, acsl

I am new to Frama-C and wanted to ask what could be causing this issue:

When I run the E-ACSL wrapper script on annotated code with no header files, the a.out.e-acsl file is properly created.

However, when I try to include header files using `-E` and `-I`, the wrapper script fails to print anything and does not generate any files.

> e-acsl-gcc.sh -E "-I src/include -I ..." main.c

I noticed that this issue happens specifically when the `-I` option is added.

I am using Frama-C 24.0 (Chromium). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a detail to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547926/how-to-include-header-files-with-e-acsl-wrapper-script) which should help here: the issue is that `e-acsl-gcc.sh` cannot handle spaces between `-I`/`-D` and its arguments.

GCC accepts both `-I dir` and `-Idir`, but for `e-acsl-gcc.sh`, only `-Idir` should be used.

So, the following should hopefully work:

```
e-acsl-gcc.sh -E "-Isrc/include -I..." main.c
```